# Why no new quasars?

Tags: quasars

Why are there no quasars younger than 13 billion years old? I have researched the emission spectrum of quasars and found only hydrogen. Could it be that after a billion years after the Big Bang, heavier elements transformed quasars into Black Holes?

Answer (score 5):

Where do you get the idea that there are no quasars younger than 13 billion years old and what do you mean by the "age" of a quasar? Also the quasar phenomenon is thought to be *due* to the accretion of matter into supermassive black holes.

Many quasars are seen at very high redshifts of 8 or so, and therefore can be no older than a billion years. There may be a problem eventually in finding younger quasars because there must be a certain amount of time required for the supermassive black holes at their centres to grow.

There appears to be a peak in the co-moving population density of quasars at redshifts of between 2 to 2.5. Depending on exactly which cosmological parameters one adopts, these quasars are about 5 billion years old (where age here refers to time since the big-bang).

The nearest quasars to us are about 1 billion light years away (e.g. 3C 273, Mkn 231), but quasars appear to be getting rarer at lower redshifts, indicating that quasars are gradually "turning off".

Thus I don't know what to make of your question - quasars are apparent over a very broad range of cosmic epochs, from about 1 billion years after the big bang to about 1 billion years in the past.

Comment: The nearest quasar is actually just 600 million light-years away (Mrk 231): https://www.nasa.gov/feature/goddard/hubble-finds-that-the-nearest-quasar-is-powered-by-a-double-black-hole

Comment: @mpv Indeed - edited. Though I'm not sure what the definition is.

Comment: Not to critique this great answer (really, I do like it), but I think by "new quasars" the OP didn't mean that they look young when we see them but ones that appear to have formed within, say, the last billion years. A quasar with a redshift of 8 may be a billion years or less old when it emitted the light we are observing, but if it's still around now, it's an old fuddy duddy quasar.

Comment: @Jim I agree about the lack of clarity. I have another answer that I placed today that explains why recent qusar activity is rare.

Comment: @Jim actually if you look a the OP carefully, the hypothesis is made that all the quasar action happened within 1 billion years of the big bang. So I don't think I have misinterpreted.

Comment: @RobJeffries Yeah, I gave you the +1 on both your quasar answers, but here I still think the was a misinterpretation. I think the hypothesis was posed as an attempt for the OP to answer their own question. The way I read it (and whether I'm right or wrong, your answer is still fitting) was as "why does there not appear to be any quasars that formed more recently than ~13 Gya? Is it perhaps because circumstances made all quasar activity only happen within 1 Gy of the Big Bang?". While your answer covers that by listing some that formed later, the misinterpretation remains.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's because you are using "age" of quasars in the more professional way that you would be used to and I think the OP is using "age" as in the time between when it supposedly formed and now (as opposed to both the time between formation and when it emitted the light we observe now as well as the age of the universe corresponding to the quasar's redshift)