# What is the difference between a quasar and an Active Galactic Nucleus (AGN)?

Tags: astrophysics, terminology, quasars

In answering another Phys.SE question about quasars - [Why no new quasars?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/213504/) - an issue arose about which object is the nearest quasar. That got me puzzled. To what is the label ["quasar"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasar) attached, as opposed to just an ["Active Galactic Nucleus"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_galactic_nucleus) (AGN)? Is it just a question of luminosity? If so, what is the threshold? Or is there something more fundamentally different about the power source that I'm missing?

It would be handy to illustrate any answer by explaining why Markarian 231 ("the closest quasar") is a quasar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no rigorous distinction between the two terms.  Any distinction is based on historical usage, and seems to be continually decreasing.

"**Active Galactic Nucleus**" (*AGN*), refers to the active *core* of a resolved galaxy.  Initially this term was purely descriptive of observations, but has now come to be used more to refer to the general (unified) class of object -- related to an active massive black-hole (MBH).  I.e. AGN has become more of a general, theoretical concept - of which there are many subtypes based on observations and physical distinctions.

"**Quasar**" comes from "Quasi-Stellar Object" (*QSO*), which originally referred to observed *point* sources of primarily optical light.  These were eventually identified to be the especially bright version of 'Seyfert' galaxies.  Often with strong radio emission.

"**Seyfert**" galaxies were originally identified as ones with peculiar spectroscopic features -- narrow- and broad- line regions (*NLR*, *BLR*), often with low to moderate radio activity.  At some point there was an arbitrary cut-off in optical brightness between quasars and seyferts.

"**Blazars**" are extremely bright point-sources in the radio, and more recently high energy (e.g. X-ray and gamma-ray).

The unified, now canonical, understanding of AGN is depicted below:

[image]

Edit:

I can't tell you why general, nearer objects than [Mrk 231](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markarian_231) aren't quasars, but Mrk231 *is* one because it has a optical, extremely-bright AGN point-source; IR excess; and both characteristic broad and narrow line regions.  Frankly, why news articles and press releases call one particular object, as opposed to another, the "nearest" of a class of ambiguously distinguished --- yet physically unified --- objects may not be very meaningful.

Comment: I'll give you a +1 then if you can tell me why it is said that the nearest quasar is Mkn 231 rather than many of the nearer AGN.

Comment: I picked up the "nearest quasar" tag from academic papers, not news stories. It seems clear as mud to me.

Comment: @RobJeffries This seems to be another one of those things with no clear definition that nobody in the field really talks about. I guess the first person to discover or reclassify an active galactic nucleus gets to decide what it is